# Get the original XY coordinates with the angle and distance

Tags: geometry

I'm working on an app with image processing. I have the positions of the little squares and the circles. I take the red circles as an origin point. Right now I'm able to get the distance and angle between those circles and the circles in the rotated image, but I'm not able to calculate the new positions for the little squares. How can I do that with the angle and distance in X and Y? The second image can be rotated and translated.

[image]

Comment: You can use $(x,y)=(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta)$.  This is called the [polar coordinate system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system).

Comment: It works with rotated and translated coordinates or only for rotated coordinates?